# how can i create a trigger which will insert values in a column depending upon input of another column of same table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

Suppose my table creation is

```
create table accident( 
  report varchar(10) primary key
  , amount number
  , "type" varchar(10));
```

I want to apply this rule:

- if my type is `'TYPE1'` my amount should have a value `10000`
- for type = `'TYPE2'` amount=`15000`
- and for `'TYPE3'` it should be `20000`

How can I create a trigger which sets `amount` depending upon value of `"type"`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how, with a few objections:

- use `VARCHAR2`, not `VARCHAR`
- why did you enclose `type` into double quotes? It isn't *reserved*

Create table:

```
SQL> create table accident
  2  ( report varchar2(10) primary key,
  3    amount number,
  4    type   varchar2(10)
  5  );

Table created.
```

Trigger: use `CASE` to set `amount` value:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_acc
  2    before insert or update on accident
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.amount := case when :new.type = 'TYPE1' then 10000
  6                        when :new.type = 'TYPE2' then 15000
  7                        when :new.type = 'TYPE3' then 20000
  8                   end;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into accident (report, type) values ('A', 'TYPE1');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into accident (report, type) values ('B', 'TYPE8');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From accident;

REPORT         AMOUNT TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
A               10000 TYPE1
B                     TYPE8

SQL> update accident set type = 'TYPE3' where report = 'B';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From accident;

REPORT         AMOUNT TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
A               10000 TYPE1
B               20000 TYPE3

SQL>
```